# How do we verify and tailor the value before assigning it to a property in Swift language?

Tags: swift

In Java, to ensure a property is assigned with a valid value, we can make the property private but have a setter method to receive and tailor a value. But what is the best practice to do the same in Swift?

It seems getter and setter methods for a stored property propagate warning messages.

Comment: What do you mean by warning messages? `All paths through this function will call itself` are the kind of messages you get?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of control you want to have over the logic of setters/getters, there are at least two approaches to that.

1. The normal Swift getter and setter pair. The thing you need to keep in mind is that if you provide custom getter/setters, then Swift won't synthesize a stored property for you. Instead you'll have to create one of your own, separate than the public `var`:

```swift
class MyClass {
    private var _myProperty: Int

    public var myProperty: Int {
        set {
            // newValue is an implicit variable
            // consider it as if you had something like setMyProperty(int newValue){}
            // in Java. Just keep in mind that newValue is immutable so you
            // cannot modify it directly, but you can assign something else to
            // _myProperty
            self._myProperty = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self._myProperty
        }
    }
}
```

Something like:

```swift
var myProperty: Int {
    set {
        self.myProperty = newValue
    }
    get {
        return self.myProperty
    }
}
```

does not work because `self.myProperty = ...` will call the `myProperty`'s setter and `return self.myProperty` will call the `myProperty`'s getter. So that's an infinite recursive call. The Java equivalent would be:

```java
public class MyClass {
    private int myProperty;

    public void setMyProperty(int newValue) {
        this.setMyProperty(newValue);
    }

    public int getMyProperty() {
        return this.getMyProperty();
    }
}
```

I know it's a bit twisted that Swift automatically calls getters/setters instead of accessing the memory of that stored property, but that's how it works.

Note that you will have to provide some default value for `_myProperty` above, either in `init` or directly where you declare the property (but that's outside the scope of the answer, I mentioned it just so you know that the above code won't compile without slight changes).

2. Use property wrappers. This is especially useful for some kind of properties that share the same get/set logic. For instance, consider the usual example of a custom setter, where you want to ensure that a numeric value is inside an interval [minValue, maxValue]. Instead of writing for every such property a custom getter and compare `newValue` with min and max values, you can share that logic inside a property wrapper:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Clamping<Value: Comparable> {
    var value: Value
    let range: ClosedRange<Value>
    
    init(wrappedValue value: Value, _ range: ClosedRange<Value>) {
        precondition(range.contains(value))
        self.value = value
        self.range = range
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set { value = max(range.lowerBound, min(newValue, range.upperBound)) }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
class MyClass {
    @Clamping(0...10) var myProperty: Int = 5
}
```

This will ensure that `myProperty` will lay between 0 and 10. There are a lot of usages of property wrappers (another example is an atomic access property) which are just some "shared getter/setter" functions applied to some properties. It's just some syntactic sugar which saves you from re-writing the same logic again and again.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I want. This kind of design makes swift value verification a little bit cumbersome.